# Implementing MarkerClusterer into Google Maps API - no markers showing

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have been trying to implement markerclusterer into my website for the past few weeks and everything I have tried has failed. I have no experience with code at all so everything I've been doing is trial and error.

The website I'm trying to add markerclusterer to is rfmaps.com.au.

I'm unsure as to what I'm doing wrong, and what needs to be fixed and really just need some good advice and help.

Here is the html code that I've been trying to get working. This code is simply all the bits and pieces I've been able to find from forums, all stuck together, and slightly edited (what I could figure out from help from forums)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var layerl0;
      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25, 133),
          zoom: 5,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
                                              data.photos[i].longitude)
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            draggable: true,
            icon: markerImage
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
        var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);

        layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: "'col2'",
            from: '1UxncvVQSGcSvuN3t686sNuDQUsn8vQ6mws3zsvk'
          },
          map: map,
          styleId: 4,
          templateId: 1
        });
      }
      function changeMapl0() {
        var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string-l0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
        layerl0.setOptions({
          query: {
            select: "'col2'",
            from: '1UxncvVQSGcSvuN3t686sNuDQUsn8vQ6mws3zsvk',
            where: "'Location' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + searchString + "'"
          }
        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <label>Location</label><input type="text" id="search-string-l0">
      <input type="button" onClick="changeMapl0()" value="Search">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is data? You'll also need to include the markerclusterer-library(it's not a part of google.maps)

Comment: [clustering example (data from xml)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html) - however, it looks like you are expecting data from your FusionTable to cluster, you can do that, but you will have to query the table for the data, then load it into the MarkerClusterer.  You can do that using the Fusion Tables v1.0 API, but access via that API is currently disabled.

Comment: @geocodezip: what do you mean by "currently disabled", I'm able to access FusionTables via the API?

Comment: Using the Fusion Tables v1.0 API to access that table I get return code 403, "Access Not Configured", which means to me that download is not allowed on that table (at least enabling downloads from that table would be the first thing I would try to fix it...).

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not added the 'map' object while creating the markers inside the map.

This is your code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: latLng,
           draggable: true,
           icon: markerImage
          });
```

Please add map: map while generating your markers, like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           map: map,
           position: latLng,
           draggable: true,
           icon: markerImage
          });
```

Regarding marker cluster you need to add this js file- markerclusterer.js

```
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, marker);
```